# Magento: reindex after import.csv (product dont show, all index are upgraded)

Tags: magento, csv, import, custom-backend, reindex

I have this problem I'm going crazy.

I imported new configurable products, see them in admin enabled, assigned to the category, assigned to the site but in front-end not seen!!

I re-updated indexes using SSH, but no result.

Moreover, there is a way to prevent that any editing I must re-index all the products? can I reindex only upgraded products or only new products.. is not possible for a single change I have to re-index from the first product!

My catalog have 25k products, but solving this i need to import other products (total 100K)

If there is among you that an expert can solve the problem, I am willing to pay (possibly an affordable price)

Regards,
Luca

Comment: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/

Comment: i've all currectly setting.. but dont see products... uffffff

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have quantity in stock (go to admin, then catalog, then look at one of the products).  If the product has 0 units in stock, it will not show in the search results.